# AWS substitution of environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, devops

I am trying to create AWS CodePipeline.
My goal is to have the following steps:

1. GetSource
2. DeployTest(substitute code variables)
3. ProductionApproval
4. DeployProduction(substitute code variables)

For point deployment, I am using "Action provider": "Amazon S3".
It makes a copy of my code into destination S3 Bucket.

Let's say my script code contains some environment variables. E.g. `${EnvironmentName}`.
How can I achieve to substitute `${EnvironmentName} = TESTENV` during Phase 2. And `${EnvironmentName} = PRODENV` in Phase 4?

Comment: What service are you using for DeployTest and DeployProduction?

Comment: If you need to change something in the source code, then you'll need a CodeBuild step to do so. The AmazonS3 action simply copies.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I am using "Amazon S3" to copy my code directly. It's static html.

Comment: @Parsifal I was thinking CodeBuild can be the idea. I just didn't want to overcomplicate my exercise. But I will give a try.
What do you think about Amplify Console? It looks as it is good to deploy things like a websites.